# NoSuchElementException in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to give input to the inputbox.i have tried using find_by_d/name and xpath also.But still getting

> File "C:\Users\1024983\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']
>     File "C:\Users\1024983\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "C:\Users\1024983\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="combobox-1023-inputEl"]"}

By using name

```
  your_input = driver.find_element_by_name("combobox-1023-inputEl")
  your_input.clear()
  your_input.send_keys("Coke")
  driver.find_element_by_name("combobox-1023-inputEl").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
  time.sleep(2)
```

By using id

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, "combobox-1023-inputEl").click()
driver.find_element(By.ID, "combobox-1023-inputEl").send_keys("Coke")
```

input box

```
<input id="combobox-1023-inputEl" type="text" role="combobox" class="x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text" autocomplete="off" name="combobox-1023-inputEl" style="width: 100%;">
```

Comment: Could you post the url that you are working with?

Comment: is the value `1023` is dynamic?

Comment: Try this `your_input = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".x-form-field.x-form-required-field.x-form-text[id*='-inputEl'][name*='-inputEl']")`

Comment: id is not dynamic ,always 1023 only @KunduK

Comment: @DivyaMani : Is that above css selector works? If not then check there must be an iframe.

Comment: not working.raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".x-form-field.x-form-required-field.x-form-text[id*='-inputEl'][name*='-inputEl']"}
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.88)

Comment: @DivyaMani : There must be an iframe can you share your url or you can check in DOM above the input element and post that iframe tag for further assistance.

Comment: @KunduK  yes it is presented in iframe and i navigated driver.switch_to.frame(0) using this code then only trying to give input value. and i can't share my url due to security reason of my Company

Comment: So after switching iframe are you able to get the input element right?or problem still persist?

Comment: Problem still persist

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a dynamic element so to send a *character sequence* with in the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.x-form-field.x-form-required-field.x-form-text[id^='combobox'][name$='inputEl']"))).send_keys("Coke")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text' and starts-with(@id,'combobox')][contains(@name,'inputEl')]"))).send_keys("Coke")
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed relevant discussion in:

- [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)

Comment: WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='x-form-field x-form-required-field x-form-text' and starts-with(@id,'combobox')][contains(@name,'inputEl')]"))).send_keys("CARA Operations LTD")
  File "C:\Users\1024983\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:   - getting this even after page load gets completed

Comment: @DivyaMani Checkout the updated answer, I have provided the link to the discussion on how to address _NoSuchElementException_.